# COM exception on Office Automation - Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, office-automation

I have developed a windows service that would read  doc / docx files and replace values based on database records and convert the replaced document as PDF.

Used Microsoft Office Interop DLL for the conversion. The service is hosted in two different machines ( Win Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - 64 Bit ). I had to 
set the Identity as Interactive User in DCOM settings to solve the exception :

### Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}failed due to the following error: 8000401a.

Initially I couldn't not find the DCOM entry for Microsoft Windows Document. So I had to change some settings in the registry following this *[link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in.aspx)*. This got me working in one system ( the service working fine). However, in another system, the service threw an exception ***Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt***  on WorkDocument.ClearFormatting() code.

To overcome that I had changed the build properties form "Any CPU" to "x86". The service worked fine for some times but it just started to throw the exception ***(Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a)*** again. I could not figure out when the service starts throwing this exception. If I restart the service it works normal but not for too long.

*I know using MS interop is not recommended for services. But i came to know about this issue only after the complete development of the service as I had no problems running the program as windows application on my system for testing purposes.*

Tried with google and have even solved the issue but the solution seems to be a temporary one for one server and the other seems to work fine. Kindly guide me to overcome the situation.

Thanks

Comment: Feels like you are looking for some workspace communication advice. SO is probably not a good place for seeking advice on getting out of case when you implemented non-working and non-supportable solution... Openly saying that you pick bad approach may be best you can do in this case...

Comment: That's CO_E_RUNAS_LOGON_FAILURE, "The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password".  That's DCOM config, you could tinker with the service's user account.  And yes, don't run Office programs in a service, they are quite difficult to troubleshoot.  As you found out.  Nastiness like them displaying a dialog and not making progress anymore is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  @HansPassant:  If it is an identity issue, the service could have not done the conversion. Am I right??? But the service does its jobs (converting word to PDF) for sometimes and starts throwing exception after sometime. If the excetpion raised, the service don't convert until it is restarted. I don't have any clue what makes the service to start throwing the exception.

Comment: Issue does not happen when a user is logged into the server. When no users are active on the server the exception is thrown.
Kindly, do shed some light on the situation. Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be the service running as an "Interactive User". Being run as an interactive user, the service runs when a user is logged in and fails if no users are active. So, I had to change the DCOM Properties' "run as" from "Interactive user" to  "This User" and setting the credentials. I also given all the permission to the selected credentials under Security Tab. The service now runs without any active users.